# How can I obtain the required output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working with some API & I managed to format the data in this order:

**Data is in this format**

```
const data = [
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 5}
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 7},
      {'type' :'b', 'rate': 2},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4},
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'b', 'rate': 1},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4}
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 8},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4}
  ]
]
```

From the above data, I want to extract point properties in this order.
**Output is required as:**

```
[
  ['a', 5, 7, 0, 8],
  ['b', 0, 2, 1, 0],
  ['c', 0, 4, 3, 4]
]
```

As I proceeded to work, I got to know I am in need of help. As I am a starter in this field, I would like to ask for some help.

I have tried doing:

```
data.forEach( (list) => {
  const group = list.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const dataType = val.type
    if(!acc[dataType]){
      acc[dataType] =[]
    }
    acc.push(dataType, val.rate)
    return acc
  }, [])
  console.log(group)
})
```

I am not able to compare two lists within an array. What is the best way to tackle this one?

Comment: Each `list` does not repeat alpha characters.  The repeated alpha characters are in other elements of the `data` array.  I would suggest flattening your `data` array first.

Comment: If I flatten my data, Would I be able to get 0 then? If a list does not contain the type, the output should be 0.

Comment: Mmm, that's a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

You could `reduce` the array. Add each `type` as a key and the array required in the output as the value in the accumulator. If the key doesn't exist yet, Add `[type, ...Array(i).fill(0)]` as the default value. If it already exists, update the `i+1` index. Add a default `0` to each array in the accumulator at the beginning because some keys could be missing in current iteration.

```js
const data=[[{type:"a",rate:5}],[{type:"a",rate:7},{type:"b",rate:2},{type:"c",rate:4},],[{type:"b",rate:1},{type:"c",rate:4}],[{type:"a",rate:8},{type:"c",rate:4}]];

const group = data.reduce((acc, arr, i) => {
  for (const type in acc)
    acc[type].push(0);

  for (const { type, rate } of arr) {
    acc[type] = acc[type] || [type, ...Array(i).fill(0)]
    acc[type][i+1] = rate
  }

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(group))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 5}
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 7},
      {'type' :'b', 'rate': 2},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4},
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'b', 'rate': 1},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4}
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 8},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4}
  ]
];

var types = [];

data.forEach( list =>
  list.forEach( element => {
    if ( !types.includes( element.type ) ) types.push( element.type );
   } )
);

console.log(
  types.reduce( ( accumulator, type ) => {
    const counts = [ type ];
    
    data.forEach( list => {
      const match = list.find( it => it.type === type );
      
      counts.push( ( match || { rate: 0 } ).rate );
    } );
    
    accumulator.push( counts );
    
    return accumulator;
  }, [] )
);
```

This version of a solution first goes through all of the elements to get a complete list of all the available types.  It then reduces each type to an array with the count of the type in each sub array.  If the element doesn't exist in the sub array, it uses a dummy object to get a `0` rate to be included in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, obviously, because I just did it like this.

Storing info by key, which is the data type.
We need to ensure we retain our max size somehow, hence the `max` variable.
Some map statements used later on to restructure into our target.

```js
const data = [
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 5}
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 7},
      {'type' :'b', 'rate': 2},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4},
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'b', 'rate': 1},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4}
  ],
  [
      {'type' :'a', 'rate': 8},
      {'type' :'c', 'rate': 4}
  ]
]

const mapping = {}
let max = 0
data.forEach( (list, i) => {
  list.forEach((val) => {
    const {type} = val
    mapping[type] = mapping[type] || []
    mapping[type][i] = val.rate
  })
  max = i
})

const result = Object.keys(mapping).map(key => {
  mapping[key][max] = mapping[key][max] || 0
  return [key, ...mapping[key]].map(val=> val || 0)
})

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result)
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it the long way...

```js
var data=[
  [{"type":"a","rate":5}],
  [{"type":"a","rate":7},{"type":"b","rate":2},{"type":"c","rate":4}],
  [{"type":"b","rate":1},{"type":"c","rate":4}],
  [{"type":"a","rate":8},{"type":"c","rate":4}]
];

var result={}, index=0;
data.forEach(list=>{
    list.forEach(item=>{
        if(!result[item.type])
          result[item.type]=
            {index:index++,type:item.type,rates:Array(data.length).fill(0)};
      }
    );
  }
);

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  data[i].forEach(item=>{
      result[item.type].rates[i]=item.rate;
    }
  );
};

var resArr=[];
Object.entries(result).forEach(r=>{
    resArr[r[1].index]=[r[0]].concat(r[1].rates);
  }
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(resArr));
```